# Problem with booting into windows when having windows and ubuntu on different disks

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I have Windows 11 installed on my SSD, and then I installed Ubuntu on my SSD. Ubuntu worked fine, but when I selected windows from the grub bootloader, it showed an error. I forgot to take note of the error, but I tried fixing it.
I have tried to enter an entry manually for windows, but then it showed an error like <<cannot find 'ntldr'>>.
So, is there anything which I can do to fix this issue? Like create a windows entry for grub manually which works?

Comment: I suggest you read `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI` . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: What is the output of *sudo parted -l*, and the output of *grep  chainloader /boot/grub/grub.cfg*? Also try running *sudo update-grub* and whether the output says it sees Windows.